# Text to Speech in Window Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, speech-synthesis

In my application I am using Text 2 Speech using SpeechSynthesizer.In my code it is speaking with only 3 voices ( One male and two females).My application is for kids so i want voice just like kids how can i achieve that?

**CODE:**

```
var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

            foreach (var voice in SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices)
            {
                synth.Voice = voice;

                var text = "Hello World";

                var stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);

                var me = new MediaElement();
                me.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
                me.Play();

                await Task.Delay(3000);
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean 'Voice just like the kids'? Do you mean higher-pitched?

Comment: I mean like kids voice not adults.

Comment: You'll probably have to do this with something like [`SharpDX`](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-xaudio2-sourcevoice). This provides some Direct-X based audio processing, specifically with XAudio2. You'll have to load in the audio stream as a Voice into it, then use something like [`SetFrequencyRatio`](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-xaudio2-sourcevoice-setfrequencyratio) to bump the frequency up a bit. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Gender and age using `StartVoice(VoiceGender gender, VoiceAge age)`

**Simple Example:**

```
PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();

pb.StartVoice(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Child);
pb.AppendText("I like my toy car");
pb.EndVoice();
```

You might want to search for TTS's that support your desired picth.

Here is the link for all languages available: [Languages](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224)

Cheers

Comment: I don't believe that the `PromptBuilder` is available for Windows Store.