# Voice control using media element in window store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am using media element in my app for playing text converted by SpeechSynthesizer.I want to know that can i control voice pitch or rate using media element??

```
var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

            var voice = Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;
            synth.Voice = voice;



            var text = "AssalamuAlaikum";

            var stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);

            var me = new MediaElement();
            me.DefaultPlaybackRate = 0.7;

            me.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
            me.Play();
```

I want to change pitch or rate to convert voice as like kids.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text to Speech in Window Store App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670729/text-to-speech-in-window-store-app)

Comment: You asked this before. People there were responding. If you wanted to clarify your question, do it there. Anyway, likely your best bets are either a third-party library or using DirectX Audio in order to manually change the pitch. One thing you could also try is generating speech via SSML as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx).

Comment: Facing one problem in above code how to select female voice ,here i select default voice which is male ,there are no other option in intellisense ,one is AllVoices?

Comment: `AllVoices` returns an array of voices. Set the `Voice` property of your `synth` object to one of the `Voice`s return in `AllVoices` to change the gender.

Comment: var voice =SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices();synth.Voice = voice; now to select female voice.

Comment: No, `AllVoices` is a *collection* of voices. A better example would be `var voice = SpeechSynthesizer.FirstOrDefault(voiceInfo => voiceInfo.Gender == VoiceGender.Female); synth.Voice = voice;`.